# powershell with cygwin openssl s_client error: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: powershell, openssl, cygwin, client

I am trying to get certificate information, and on my local desktop its working without issue.  I needed to move to a server where it does not work and gives the unknown protocol error. Here is the command:

```
echo quit |  openssl s_client -showcerts -connect xxx:xxxx
```

Adding any of the flags below in any combination does not remove the error. I have searched all over the internet and tried about every solution I could find. Nothing has worked.

```
echo quit |  openssl s_client -ignore_critical -debug -bugs -prexit -verify -no_ssl2 -no_ssl3 -no_tls1 -showcerts -tls1_1 -connect xxx:xxxx
```

The version of Cygwin is the same, as are the installed libraries, version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015 . I checked, double checked, triple checked this. Powershell and .net are the same versions as well. What IS different is Windows version. Working version is Windows 7. Non working version is windows 2012. Could this be the issue? Hoping someone here knows the answer.

I ran the debug command from the cygwin command line and get the following:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x6000705d0 [0x60007a483] (208 bytes => 208 (0xD0))

<<<<< followed by hex dump many lines >>>>>>

2348672:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:

---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 316 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
```

I have also looked at cert manager but do not see any differences in the two boxes. I am thinking I may have missed something here, though I did not add any certs to get this to work initially.

Anyone have any ideas here? I hope so..

EDIT: I had tried the -servername flag some time ago and that did not help either. The server I am reaching is behind a firewall and not reachable by anyone outside my local network, hence why I put xxx in there for IP.  The good news is the comment saying it looked as though SSL was not happening led me down the correct path. The destination server was not configured correctly for the new server I was using. It sent back that error message instead of a more useful one.  Issue is resolved. Thanks everyone for the comments and assistance. Anyone reading this in the future, check your destination server if nothing else works.

Comment: What server are you connecting to with this command? The same as with the command on the other machine where this works? That error appears to be indicating that the server you are connecting to is not presenting an SSL certificate (and that perhaps it isn't even speaking SSL at all).

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the same machine where it worked, a machine in house on the same network. I essentially took the powershell script and placed it on the new server. Made no changes and it didn't work. The working machine shows debug of: New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA .  So it is speaking either SSLv3 or TLSv1.  I find it odd those two are combined together.

Comment: I would probably check that the new server is correctly connecting to the expected server (with a packet capture on both ends) and that the original server was connecting to the expected server as well. (Just in case there's a firewall/proxy/etc. in the way for some reason.) Assuming that's not the case then the packet capture might tell you about something else going on with the new server's connection.

Comment: *"...`<<<<< followed by hex dump many lines >>>>>>`..."* - I how the first read did *not* include ***`HTTP 1.0`***. You need to provide real information. We cannot duplicate with *`-connect xxx:xxxx`*. In the meantime, try `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect xxx:xxxx -servername xxx`. Usually, you want to operate with TLS 1.0 and above *with* SNI.

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname>`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.